# App crashes when EditText is Empty or null - how to solve it

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView4 = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    editTextNumberDecimal2 = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal2);
    editTextNumberDecimal3 = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal3);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String s = editTextNumberDecimal2.getText().toString();
            int kg = Integer.parseInt(s);
            double pound = kg;
            String k = editTextNumberDecimal3.getText().toString();
            int cms = Integer.parseInt(k);
            double ft = cms;
            double bmi = (pound / ft / ft) * 10000;

            if (bmi < 18.5) {
                textView4.setText("Thin - Eat something");
            }
            else if (bmi < 25) {
                textView4.setText("Fit - Keep it up");
            }
            else if (bmi < 30) {
                textView4.setText("Fat - Go on a diet");
            }
            else {
                textView4.setText("Very fat - Stop eating");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}
..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................ignore these dots......................................................................................................................

Comment: look at the error logs.. search the error on google... and read about the error "when and why we get that error ?..eg- nullPointerException in your case probably..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot parse an empty string to an integer. So check it first if it's empty or not.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String s = editTextNumberDecimal2.getText().toString();
    if(s.isEmpty()) return;
    int kg = Integer.parseInt(s);
    double pound = kg;
    String k = editTextNumberDecimal3.getText().toString();
    if(k.isEmpty()) return;
    int cms = Integer.parseInt(k);
    // ...
}
```